# What is an equivalent of "apt-key add" command in yum

Tags: linux, apt, yum, aws

I'm trying to run a command from nginx documentation `sudo apt-key add nginx_signing.key`, but I think AWS Linux uses Yum so this command fails. What would be an equivalent command to it in Yum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question was published [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65037398/13284630). Here is the content:

##### Below is from an article on [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/yum-and-apt) which I think answers this questions properly:

Adding a repository in YUM is a manual operation, which consists in creating a file with the .repo extension under the folder /etc/yum.repos.d.

The file must contain all the information about the custom repository that we are connecting to.

Let’s try adding the AdoptOpenJDK repository:

```
# /etc/yum.repos.d/adoptopenjdk.repo
[AdoptOpenJDK]
name=AdoptOpenJDK
baseurl=http://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/rpm/centos/7/$(uname -m)
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/api/gpg/key/public
```

In APT, though, things are quite different. The GPG key of the repository must be downloaded and added to the APT keyring with apt-key add:

```
wget -qO - https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/api/gpg/key/public | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then, at this point, the repository can be added through add-apt-repository –yes followed by the URL:

```
add-apt-repository --yes https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/deb/
```

Contrary to YUM, all the repositories are saved in a single file, `/etc/apt/sources.list`.